# How to cat the docker's ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker

Suppose we have the following docker image: `osimis/orthanc-dicom-syncher`. We have no `Dockerfile` or code repository present (except what we could obtain through `docker history`).

That docker image has a python script as it's `entrypoint` (like in `/usr/local/bin/orthanc-dicom-syncher`). I want to see that script's contents, but, unfortunately, the container stops immediately after running. That rules out `bash`-ing into container to cat the necessary file.

Moreover, if i try to `docker run`, docker passes the whole command as an arguments to python script.

I've tried to workaround it like:

1. `docker commit <orthanc-dicom-syncher_contained_id> my-broken-container`
2. `docker run -it my-broken-container /bin/bash`

But this again runs the `/bin/bash` part as an argument to the python script (yielding `orthanc-dicom-syncher: error: unrecognized arguments: /bin/bash`).

Any advice how to (ideally) `bash` into the container or (sufficiently) to extract entrypoint's code would be appreciated.

*There is no github repo with that image, so i couldn't find the code on the net; anyway, even if it were, i am curious how to solve this problem*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And, as it is constantly happens, formulating the question helped me to solve the issue.

The solution is to override the `entrypoint` with `--entrypoint` flag:

`docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/cat" my-broken-container /usr/local/bin/orthanc-dicom-syncher`

Be mindful of the command and arguments positioning (see [this](https://medium.com/@oprearocks/how-to-properly-override-the-entrypoint-using-docker-run-2e081e5feb9d) post).

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following:

```
docker create --name test osimis/orthanc-dicom-syncher
docker cp test:/usr/local/bin/orthanc-dicom-syncher .
```

then you find the files in your working directory

**PS**
make sure that you allowed to use them or modify them, I am not aware of the `Term of use`